# How can I test for the result of some asynchronous process?

Tags: java, testing, asynchronous, junit

I'm testing a component which wraps a Quartz `Scheduler` object.

My problem is that Quartz is doing some asynchronous processing internally and I can't write in my test code something like this:

```
    Mockito.when(configurationMock.getId()).thenReturn(CONFIG_ID);
    target.addJob(configurationMock);
    Scheduler sched = (Scheduler) Whitebox.getInternalState(target, "scheduler");
    assertTrue(sched.checkExists(new JobKey(configurationMock.getId())));
```

because it is possible that when I check the job's existence it is not there yet.

I checked the JUnit API but there is no `assertWithTimeout()` or something like that. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally use a CountDownLatch - but it requires some form of callback method, something like:

```
CountDownLatch done = new CountDownLatch(1);
target.onJobComplete(new Runnable() { public void run() {
    done.countdown();
}});
Scheduler sched = (Scheduler) Whitebox.getInternalState(target, "scheduler");
done.await(timeout);
```

If you don't have a callback or a way to check if the task has been scheduled yet, you could simply wait:

```
target.addJob(configurationMock);
Scheduler sched = (Scheduler) Whitebox.getInternalState(target, "scheduler");

//wait up to 1 second
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    if (!sched.checkExists(new JobKey(configurationMock.getId()))) Thread.sleep(10);
    else break;
}

assertTrue(sched.checkExists(new JobKey(configurationMock.getId())));
```